# How to fill Charts.js with mysql data?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below is my code, and I want in xaxis and yaxis to display my data from database.

```
 <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var barChartData = {
    labels : <?=json_encode(array_values($count));?>,
    datasets : [

        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data :<?=json_encode(array_values($auditor));?>
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}

</script>
```

My php code is this:

```
<?php

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
                or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db('laravel') or die('Could not select database');

        $auditor = array();
        $sql = "SELECT DATE(created) AS date, COUNT(auditor_id) AS 'count' FROM auditor WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-31 23:59:59' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $date = $row["date"];
                $count = $row["count"];
                //add to data array
                $auditor[$date] = $count;
            }
        }
```

Basically I want those data after grouped to display in the X axis and Y axis

Comment: What you want to display in label(x-axis) ?

Comment: After I group the data I will have the count and date column so I want the date to be in x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made date and count array separately. and convert it in json. 
I have used this url for reference. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-example-usage

I have not tested this code in my local. So please first test it in your system. I think it will get you more idea.

First change it in your php code.

```
if ($result) {
        $dates = array();
        $counts = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $dates[]  = $row["date"];
            $counts[] = $row["count"];
        }
    }
```

Now set this values in your jquery code.

```
var barChartData = {
labels : <?=json_encode($dates);?>,
datasets : [

    {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data :<?=json_encode($counts);?>
    }
]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Just change this line**

**`<?=json_encode(array_values($count));?>`**

> **to**

**`<?=json_encode(array_keys($auditor));?>`**